# Navigation version in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am new to Android Studio and I am trying to use the latest navigation version which I believe is 2.3.0. However, after adding it to the dependencies in the gradle file I still seem to get an error that it could not find the classpath. Any tips? Here are some screenshots:

[image: The dependencies and the navigation]
[image: The error message]

Comment: Try this instead `classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"`

Comment: Ah ok, that builds. The classpath I had there was from one of the tutorials in Kotlin. However, it says that I should have access to a GameFragmentDirections class in the java generated folder, but it's not recognised.

Comment: What version of Studio are you using? Studio 4.1 Beta 1 and 4.2 Canary 2 had an issueswith Directions classes not being recognized by Studio.

Comment: Android Studio 4.0
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 x86_64
I think this, 4.0 I am assuming?

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the help! For anyone having problems with getting a directions class, this solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686907/safeargs-library-doesnt-generate-direction-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using:

```
classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
```

It was the 1st release and the latest version is `1.0.0`

With **androidx** migration you have to use:

```
def nav_version = "2.3.0"
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
```

More info in the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#ensure_type-safety_by_using_safe_args).