# Safe Args do not generate classes

Tags: android, kotlin

I have read the other threads on this but still can't get it to work.
I've added,

```
def nav_version = "2.3.5"
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
```

To the Project Gradle, and:

`id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'`

To the app Gradle file.

I have:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in the gradle.properties file

I've followed the tutorials to the letter, adding argument but still I don't get the direction or any other classes generated once I rebuild the project.

What am I missing?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62568138/11718077) might be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using kotlin (as infered from your tags) and an alternative way is to use the plugin for Safe Args just in Kotlin:

build.gradle (:project):

```
buildscript {
    ext.nav_version = "2.3.5"
    
    dependencies {
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}
```

build.gradle (:app):

```
plugins {
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}
```

Verify:

- Kotlin >= 1.4
- Android Studio >= 4.2.

Comment: No luck :( 
I'm using  Android Studio Arctic Fox 
I don't know if it makes any difference, I'm using gradle:7.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer was found, thanks to @anshul:
The problem is not that the files are not generated, they are.
But, the IDE does not find them. As I am using Kotlin, the answer is a bit different from that for Java.

You must add to your app-level Gradle

```
android {
...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            kotlin {
//                srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/navigation-args/'
                srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/example/navanddata/ui/'
            }
        }
```

In my IDE, if you use the first (commented out) line, you get a multitude of folders that appear in your IDE sidebar. But if you go for the second, you must update it to your project name and update it for DBG / REL compilation.

In both cases, you will have to look for the files for a bit as they do not appear where you would expect, rather (in the second option) under a folder called Kotlin are “root level”.